# The eye of truth

Tags: riddle

Someone still thinks *cleaning the cellar is boring*? Well, not for me ...
Where do I begin?

I don't really know how to describe all this so I took some pictures for you. I've found this really strange thing which is probably called *"THE EYE OF TRUTH"* (see the pictures below).

[image]

There are 6 small marble-like orbs elevated above some kind of small cups where they seem to fit in (I didn't touch them because I was too afraid of what they could do to me).
If you look closely you can see that the surrounding orbs are glowing, whereas the one in the middle looks dark.

*Maybe it will light up when we solve the mystery?*

[image]

There also was a piece of paper with some weird inscriptions, which don't tell me a thing. I can also see that other people have tried before, making it hard for me to focus on the riddle. Someone's even crossed out some lines... probably to make it even more unsolvable for others.
In addition to that, it looks like the part on the top right burned. Let's hope we can guess it after we understand all the rest!

[image]
*(It's not a Kandinsky. Click to enlarge)*

---

I really want to find out what's all behind this!

So far I'm wondering:

- Where do we have to put the orbs and should we put in anything else?
- What will the orb in the centre show?

Now I have no idea where to begin... can someone help?

---

Hints

> - First we should solve the riddle/poem
>  - The solution might be more simple than one might expect
>  - Make that 2nd one "excitement" (was hard to rhyme properly)
>  - The missing stanza could be anything, we don't know much about it
>  - After we get the right idea filling in that last element will be easy
>  - The riddle leads to a set of words
>  - We only need a part of each of those words (some users already found that)
>  - How are the final letters related? And why the hexagonal shape?
>  - "get hands on the key" or should I say "get hands on the keys"?

---

> I also have the feeling you could make use of this image for your solution:
>  [image]

Comment: Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I can see a true believer!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Forgot the Zalgo

Comment: Ha. I thought that was more likely than "content"...

Comment: Does the [tag:steganography] tag apply here or could you solve the puzzle with a plain printing of the images?

Comment: @EngineerToast No steganography here.

Comment: I'd be interested to know whether you had a specific answer in mind for the sixth riddle, and indeed whether you had a specific sixth riddle leading to it...

Comment: I really had one, yes. But since it should represent the unknown I shall keep it to myself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given C Woods's solution to the verse riddles and Avigrail's correction to one of them, so far we have

> FEAR EXCITEMENT ___
>  SADNESS CONFUSION RAGE

It is obvious to guess that

> the initial letters might be significant. These are FE_SCR.

There are all sorts of semi-plausible guesses one might make about what to do with these, but Avigrail's most recent hint is a biggie and the key point (I choose my words with care) is that

> FESCR are five of the six letters arranged hexagonally around the D on a standard QWERTY typewriter or computer keyboard. The sixth is X.

This suggests that we should

> write the letters FESCRX on small slips of paper, or procure appropriate Scrabble pieces -- or perhaps even keyboard keycaps -- and place them in the outer orbs, clockwise (starting at top left, if there's some way that the apparatus makes it clear where that is) in the order ERFCXS.

Perhaps when we do so

> a D will appear in the central orb. (And perhaps it will also summon eldritch horrors from another universe, but let's not be too pessimistic.)

The remaining question is what that sixth riddle might be. Its answer

> seems like it needs to be a word beginning with X; but another option is that EXCITEMENT actually indicates X and we need a word beginning with E instead.

For obvious reasons, the second of these is an easier choice. Continuing the theme of the existing solutions, observing the shortage of space for the missing riddle, and trying to match the fragments of text we can see, perhaps it is something like this (though I hope Avigrail has done better):

> For all the world's
>  Difficulties
>  I give release

with solution

> I am EASE.

Mysteries that remain unexplained:

> The paper is folded in a peculiar way.
>  Someone has written "3x3" on it.
>  There are lots of other scribblings, but I cannot make any sense of them. (Perhaps they are just writing-like scribbles but not actual words, planted by Avigrail to confuse.)
>  Diagrams -- some with circular arcs, some with parallel straight lines. Do they have significance? (One of them is a bit *eye*-like.)

Comment: Now you can go through the second part of the page again and eventually open the gate!

Comment: I can't quite work out whether that indicates that I got something right (besides what was already known) or whether it's just a polite way of saying "OK, enough blathering, now why don't you solve the puzzle?"...

Comment: (I have of course looked at the second part of the page in the hope that it will make things clearer, but so far it hasn't.)

Comment: Any chance the burnt part could stand for 'FOld THis (some way)' and not a 6th rhyme?

Comment: Anything's possible, but that would really surprise me. (Though it might help explain why the apparently-burned patch is so small.) I can't quite work out whether the burned patch is meant to be a hole in the paper, or to have been patched with other paper. You'd think the former, but some of the writing extends onto it. Perhaps just imperfect image-manipulation by Avigrail, but s/he seems to have been pretty thorough about this.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I did actually burn it. No image manipulation!

Comment: Commendably thorough! But is there really "no image manipulation"? That "woven" effect seems to continue continuously off the edge of the paper, to remain horizontal/vertical even when the paper is at an angle in 3D, etc...

Comment: I don't think it can be "Fold" -- you'd see the top of the "l". I think it's "For".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ok there is manipulation but only for style ;)

Comment: The center part starts to become brighter as Gareth puts in the letters one by one until it enlightens the room with a warm flare. "eldritch horrors" shall not appear but other than that Gareth was right, well *D*one! - I thought someone would accidentally name the second one "X" since it is unknown (like we do in maths). The philosphical approach is that together with basic emotions there is always the unknown/chance/luck/... and the second riddle describes that in whatever mysterious way you want ;)

Comment: Aha, so it was an "unknown X" rather than merely an unknown "X" :-).

Comment: Very disappointed by the absence of brain-curdling eldritch horrors, though.

Answer (score 8):

**Partial Answer**

It looks like the six riddles clue towards

> Paul Ekman's six basic emotions.

I am a great defender/ To me people surrender/ But to you I'm not dear

> I am fear.

A rush with pleasure/ Often I go with leisure/ I'm big with every event

> I am content. (happiness, but probably easier to rhyme content without giving away the answer :) )

World's greatest shield/To me will surely yield/ I'm escorting the madness

> I am sadness.

No clue around here/ let the system disappear/ I'm quite the delusion

> I am confusion. (Or surprise, again easier to rhyme I'm guessing.)

Both young and old/ A solid grudge I hold/ I do not care for age

> I am rage.

The only

> basic emotion that is missing is disgust.

Not sure where to go from there though. I imagine these have to do with the six orbs around the hexagon.

Comment: I don't know Paul Ekman I must say. But anyway you got some things right here +1

Answer (score 7):

Plaintext version of the text on the paper:

```
I am a great        A rush with         Fo-------------
defender            pleasure            th---------------

To me people        Often I go with     -----------------
surrender           leisure             ---------------

But to you I'm not  I'm big with eve--  ----------
dear                event               --------

------------------  ------------------  -----------------
------------------  ------------------  -----------------

World's greatest    No clue around      Both young and
shield              here                old

To me will surely   let the system      A solid grudge I
yield               disappear           hold

I'm escorting the   I'm quite the       I do not care for
madness             delusion            age

------------------  ------------------  -----------------
------------------  ------------------  -----------------

Behold! Only the chosen will see
And those who are worthy may open the gate
First of all you need to get hands on the key
If only the answers you could state
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: It doesn't, but it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

> [The six Infinity/Soul gems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems) from [the Marvel Universe.](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Gems)

And the hexagonal structure is for

> the [resurrection of Nemesis,](http://marvel.com/universe/Nemesis_(Infinity_Gems_Restored)) by using another gem on the center([Ego gem](http://marvel.com/universe/Ego_Gem)).

### ---

Explanation:

"THE EYE OF TRUTH"

> `I am a great       A rush with           Fo-------------
>   defender            pleasure            th---------------`
>
> > [Agamotto](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Agamotto_(Earth-616)) and one of the eyes he created. He defended Earth(and the Universe) multiple times. 'A rush with pleasure' might refer to the way with which he was born by his mother, [Oshtur](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Oshtur_(Earth-616)).

---

> `To me people        Often I go with     -----------------
>   surrender           leisure             ---------------`
>
> > [Thanos](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Thanos_(Earth-616)), and his [obsession with Infinity gauntlet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Gauntlet)

---

> `But to you I'm not  I'm big with eve--  ----------
>   dear                event               --------`
>
> > [Galactus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Galactus_(Earth-616)), because he's literally humongous!

---

> `World's greatest    No clue around      Both young and`
>   `shield              here                old`
>
> > [Captain America](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_(Steven_Rogers)), and [his shield being broken](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135001/29106) numerous time, he had no clue when he woke up from the cryogenic sleep.

---

> `To me will surely   let the system      A solid grudge I
>   yield               disappear           hold`
>
> > Again, Galactus!

---

`I'm escorting the   I'm quite the       I do not care for
madness             delusion            age`

> [Silver Surfer](http://marvel.com/universe/Silver_Surfer), as the herald of Galactus!

---

---

> Behold! Only the chosen will see
>   And those who are worthy may open the gate
>   First of all you need to get hands on the key
>   If only the answers you could state.
>
> > This is probably: [Doctor Strange](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Stephen_Strange_(Earth-616))!!

---

> The underlying connect in all these is : [Infinity War.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_War)

Comment: Wow that's some work you did! But unfortunately you are far off. As always my riddles include a couple of steps and a simple solution like a word or number

Answer (score -1):

Is possible that each one of the emotions submitted before are related to a colour and with a code of colours we get the clue on how to obtain the last sphere?

> Rage --> Red
>
>  Fear --> Green
>
>  Sadness --> Blue
>
>  Excitement --> Orange
>
>  Confusion --> Yellow
>
>  Disgust --> Violet

Similar to a rainbow, so we lack 1 colour that would fit in the last space left.